# Short Story versus Novel format

Tags: publishing, formatting, content-strategy

I have just completed a draft erotic short story I have never professionally published fiction before but I believe this story "sizzles".  This story is around 4000 words.  I have rough plans to write several more short stories using the same characters and possibly even venture into the LGBT arena.  Would it be more financially rewarding to publish as series of short stories or to combine into longer novel?  Does anybody have recommendations on publishers that work with you to help publish work?  Especially in areas like cover design.  I am a novice; however, I do not want to have to pay a large sum upfront for help.  I would rather have the help come out of royalties.  I want to have it published as a e-book and possibly audiobook.  Does Amazon/Kindle accept "HOT" works on their site or is it mostly family friendly stories.  I would gratefully accept advise from anyone who has experience in this genre

Comment: "Would it be more financially rewarding to publish as series of short stories or to combine into longer novel?" Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but the answer is probably 'no'. It's very difficult for most people to make any significant amount of money from writing. And while you could make the choice between short stories and a novel based on financial considerations, they are two very different things, so you'll probably do better writing whichever you prefer, and doing it as well as you possibly can. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

As a reader I'd buy a collection of short stories rather than a single story in this case. When buying a single short story the organizational overhead and cover work will have a relative larger impact on the price. With a collection I expect to get a better deal.

I wouldn't worry about the cover design. The challenge is finding your publisher. Search for erotic books on the market, make a list of their publishers and contact them.

Amazon sells even works by Marquis de Sade whose works I'd count amongst the most perverted literature in the world. I'm sure your erotic stories can be published there. However, that's true for Europe but Amazon's product catalog of course varies in different countries.